# Copy some table records into the same table make some problems

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl, transactionscope, 4gl

```
DEFINE BUFFER bfSource FOR tableA.
DEFINE BUFFER bfTarget FOR tableA.

DO FOR bfTarget TRANSACTION:
    FOR EACH bfSource  WHERE  bfSource.user_id = 0 NO-LOCK:
        CREATE bfTarget.
        BUFFER-COPY bfSource  EXCEPT id TO bfTarget.
        ASSIGN 
            bfTarget.user_id = 1.
    END.
END.
```

When i use this query the last iteration can randomly couse some problems.
The AVM try to find the next record, but their is none, sometimes the AVM finds the new created record (before the user_id is <> 0). I have some ideas to prevent this , horribil to find, bug, but i dont know what is best practise. I also tryed to change the position of the transaction scope with no effect.

Comment: Posting the errors you encounter would be useful for figuring out what's gone wrong. And in general, for questions about tables (db or temp-) showing the schema - fields and indexes - helps a lot too.

Comment: It is only an example, i get no error, even with only the id field and without buffer-copy the problem can occur. In the last iteration i copy the previously created record becous the avm finds it before the id is <> 0.

Answer (score 0):

My solution , at the moment, is:

```
DEFINE BUFFER bfSource FOR tableA.
DEFINE BUFFER bfTarget FOR tableA.

REPEAT PRESELECT EACH bfSource WHERE bfSource.user_id = 0 NO-LOCK:
    FIND NEXT bfSource.
    DO FOR bfTarget TRANSACTION:
        CREATE bfTarget.
        BUFFER-COPY bfSource  EXCEPT id TO bfTarget.
        ASSIGN 
            bfTarget.user_id = 1.
    END.
END.
```

Comment: You can have the `ASSIGN` be part of the `BUFFER-COPY` statement (the `.`  after `bfTarget` makes it a separate statement.